# Is there any replacement for the chainrings of a Shimano STX crankset?

Tags: mountain-bike, repair, parts, shimano, replacement

I have a Shimano STX Crankset (probably FC-MC series or similar, around 2001) with worn out chainrings (5 Arms). Is there any contemporary replacement opportunity for either the chainrings or the whole crankset?

Comment: Sheldon to the rescue: http://sheldonbrown.com/bbsize.html#stx

Answer (score 2):

Just look for any chainrings that have the same [bolt circle diameter](http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_bo-z.html), the same number of bolts, and are designed for the same number of gears that you currently have and you'll be fine.

Although you may find that it's cheaper to simply replace the whole crankset than to buy individual chainrings.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I already tried the total replacement and learned the hard way that a Shimano FC-M171 doesn't fit (Smallest Chainring touches chainstay). Chainline is identical though. Is there any crankset that could fit?